Integrate function involving Mod[]
I have a function
f[x_] := Min[Mod[a x, 2], 2 - Mod[a x, 2]]

that I want to integrate
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2/a}]

Clearly, the function equals a x when x<1/a, and 2-a x when x>=1/a.
The integral should therefore return 1/a, since it is the surface area of two triangles with base width 1/a and height 1.
However, Mathematica gives me 1/(2a). What have I done wrong?
The code below illustrates it with a graph, and reproduces the issue.
subs = a -> 3
f[x_] := Min[Mod[a x, 2], 2 - Mod[a x, 2]]
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2/a}]
N[% //. subs]
Plot[f[x] //. subs, {x, 0, 2/a //. subs}]

Help is appreciated!

It seems to be a bug even if a has a complex values still the correct answer is not 1/(2 a). See my answer for workaround.

Adding Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals solves the problem.
Integrate[Min[Mod[a x, 2], 2 - Mod[a x, 2]], {x, 0, 2/a}, 
 Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals]


$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{a} & a>0\lor a<0 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$
Or Assumptions -> a > 0.
Integrate[Min[Mod[a x, 2], 2 - Mod[a x, 2]], {x, 0, 2/a}, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]


1/a

Or Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && a != 0.
Integrate[Min[Mod[a x, 2], 2 - Mod[a x, 2]], {x, 0, 2/a}, 
 Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && a != 0]

1/a


The integral under consideration makes sense for complex values of  a != 0 too. Indeed, Mathematica finds definite integrals along complex lines (see Integrate/Scope/Definite Integrals) using the Newton-Leibniz formula. If we parametrize complex line from 0 to 2/a by x==2/a*t, then  t changes from 0 to 1, taking real values and a*x changes from 0 to 2, also taking real values. We start from the simplification
integrand =  FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[Min[FunctionExpand[Mod[a x, 2]], 
2 - FunctionExpand[Mod[a x, 2]]]], Assumptions -> a*x >= 0 && a*x <= 2]


Piecewise[{{a*x, a*x <= 1}, {2 - a*x, Inequality[1, Less, a*x,  Less, 2]}}, -2 + a*x]

Now we find the antiderivative of the integrand by the change of the variable.
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][integrand, x], t, x == 2/a*t]


Inactive[Integrate][ (2*InputForm[Piecewise[{{2 - 2*t, Inequality[1/2, Less, t,  Less, 1]}, {-2 + 2*t, t >= 1}}, 2*t]])/a, t]

int = Activate[Inactive[Integrate][(2 Piecewise[{{2 - 2 t, 1/2 < t < 1}, 
{-2 + 2 t, t >= 1}}, 2 t])/a,  t], Unevaluated[Integrate]]


Piecewise[{{(2*t^2)/a, t <= 1/2}, {-a^(-1) + (4*t - 2*t^2)/a,  Inequality[1/2, Less, t, LessEqual, 1]}},  3/a + (4*(-t + t^2/2))/a]

To finish we apply the Newton-Leibniz formula:
int /. t -> 1 - int /. t -> 0


1/a


Thank you! But in my case, a is real ...

@BoudewijnVerhaar: As written Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2/a}] in the question , a is not assumed real. You only check 1/(2a) for a==3. Aso see the comment of azerbajdzan "It seems to be a bug even if a has a complex values still the correct answer is not 1/(2 a). See my answer for workaround" to your question.

Indeed you're correct, I forgot to mention that, and I also forgot to mention this to Mathematica.
